# Given two series $ x_n $ and $ y_n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $ x_n = \sum_{k=n}^{\ 2n-1} \frac{1}{k} $ , $ y_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\ 2n} \frac{1}{k} $

b) Show that $ y_n \leq \ln2 \leq x_n $ for all $n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approximate the sums with definite integrals from above and below (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum#Approximation_by_definite_integrals)):
$$
y_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k\le\int_n^{2n}x^{-1}\mathrm dx=\ln2+\ln n-\ln n=\ln 2
$$
and
$$
x_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac1k\ge\int_n^{2n}x^{-1}\mathrm dx=\ln 2.
$$

Comment: Okay I will try to understand. Now I want to show that both $ x_n $ and $ y_n $ converge to $ ln2 $ for $ n $ going to infinity. Can I just say that, beacuse of they are limited then they converge, and the series converge if the integral converge. Is that right.

Comment: @AlimTeacher You can use the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) to show that $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge to $\ln 2$ as $n\to\infty$. We have that $$\ln 2\le x_n\le \int_{n-1}^{2n-1}x^{-1}\mathrm dx=\ln\Bigl(\frac{2n-1}{n-1}\Bigr)=\ln2+\ln\Bigl(\frac{n-1/2}{n-1}\Bigr)$$ and $\ln\bigl(\frac{n-1/2}{n-1}\bigr)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ since $\frac{n-1/2}{n-1}\to1$  as $n\to\infty$. Similarly, you can show that $y_n$ converges to $\ln 2$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: okay, but why do you choose the lower limit to be n-1

Comment: @AlimTeacher For decreasing function $f$,
$$
\sum_{i=a}^bf(i)\le\sum_{i=a}^b\int_{i-1}^if(s)\mathrm ds=\int_{a-1}^bf(s)\mathrm ds
$$
since $f(i)\le\int_{i-1}^if(s)\mathrm ds$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum#Approximation_by_definite_integrals)).

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Try to commute the left and right Riemann sum of the function $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+x}$ on $(1,2)$.